# Проблемы со слайдером

Tags: slick.js

при переключении слайдов на главной с помощью стрелки вперед (в гугл хроме) появляется белая полоса на долю секунды (выглядит как блик) ...помогите разобраться в чем тут причина (в мозиле все отлично работает). Slick slider используется , изображения  сжаты. (вот сайт http://sina.seoimpiu.beget.tech/ )

Comment: У меня всё работает. Накручиваете счётчик?

Comment: все работает . Там при прокрутке есть блик ( белая полоса на пол слайдера в левой части )...Это можно заметить если крутить с помощью стрелки вперед в хроме

Comment: Уловил блик, но это надо на стрелку тыкать с бешенной скоростью, разве кто-то будет так листать ? 

А вообще у слика частенько что-то такое вылезает...

Comment: заказчик записал видос ,как у него бликует...и его это не устраивает.(((